# gulp gulp-sass source string:1: error: file to import not found or unreadable: "susy"

Tags: sass, gulp, susy-sass

Need assistance with getting gulp/gulp-sass to recognize susy. Im running out of ideas and need a 2nd set of eyes. Thank you for feedback.

Error:

```
[gulp] [gulp-sass] source string:1: error: file to import not found or unreadable: "susy"
```

gem list

```
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
rubyzip (1.0.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.3.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.37.0)
slop (3.4.6)
sorcerer (1.0.2)
susy (2.1.2)
```

Config.rb

```
require 'susy'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'susy'
```

Gulp

```
var paths = {
sass: ['sass/main.scss'],
scripts: ['js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', 'js/*.js'],
images: 'img/**/*'
};
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

Comment: [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) uses [lib-sass](https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass) which is not compatible with ruby gems. Maybe try [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass)?

Comment: @steveax flipped to gulp-ruby-sass and I get this: [gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass': Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.

Comment: What version of Sass does gulp-ruby-sass use? Susy 2 requires Sass 3.3+.

Comment: @EricMSuzanne - it uses what is installed and it currently is sass (3.3.7) on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to gulp-ruby-sass and configuring per below solved the issue:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
   return gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sass({require: ['susy']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```